# What is the difference between a wilted salad and a massaged salad?

Tags: flavor, salad, texture, greens

What is the general difference between preparations and use cases of a wilted salad compared to a massaged salad? As many wilted salad recipes call for warm dressing, does this mean the wilted salad will lend itself better toward cooked ingredients compared to massaged or raw greens? Does wilting the greens in the salad have any particular impact on the profile of the flavor and texture of the end result that gears it toward pairing with flavors that massaged greens, or raw, would not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've only heard of massaging kale.  If you rub the greens together they get softer, darker and more tender and useable in a salad.  Never done it with anything else. Wilted is steamed or blanched greens. Wilting definitely changes the texture and can make the greens more palatable and less bitter.  I won't eat raw collards. I also always salt and squeeze my cooked spinach before using as it knocks out the bitterness.